# JButton is overlapping the JPanel in my Student Management Software

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am beginner in java, I am trying to make a student management software but I am facing this problem : The JButton is overlaping the Jpanel.

```
package project;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class Home implements MouseListener  {
    
    JFrame jf;
    JLabel jl,loginpanelimg;
    JButton login_bt, add_bt, search_bt, remove_bt;
    JPanel loginPanel, searchPanel, addPanel, removePanel;
    
    
    public void start () {
        
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(1280,720);
        jf.setLocation(120,60);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setUndecorated(false);
        
        
        jl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("E:\\Best one\\design\\Home pagejpgg.jpg"));
        jl.setBounds(0,0,1280,720);
        
        loginpanelimg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("E:\\Best one\\design\\Login panel.png"));
        loginpanelimg.setBounds(0,0,980,560);
        
        
        login_bt = new JButton("Login");
        login_bt.setBounds(122, 337, 143, 183);
        login_bt.addMouseListener(this);
        
        add_bt = new JButton("Add Data");
        add_bt.setBounds(402, 337, 143, 183);
        
        search_bt = new JButton("Search Data");
        search_bt.setBounds(724, 337, 143, 183);
        
        remove_bt = new JButton("Remove Data");
        remove_bt.setBounds(1004, 337, 143, 183);
        
        loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.setLayout(null);
        loginPanel.setBounds(150,80,980,560);
        loginPanel.setVisible(false);
        
        
        
        loginPanel.add(loginpanelimg);
        jf.add(loginPanel);
        jf.add(remove_bt);
        jf.add(search_bt);
        jf.add(add_bt);
        jf.add(login_bt);
        jf.add(jl);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        
        
        if(e.getSource()==login_bt) {
            
            loginPanel.setVisible(true);
            
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}

public class project {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        
        Home h = new Home();
        h.start();
        
    }
    
}
```

As shown in the image Whenever i run the program and open the panel and move the cursor, all the button starts appearing on the JPanel.

[image]

Comment: I am afraid you trying to mix too many components that swing does not like in this way. Maybe this article would help you? 
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Hey Sunny, Not to sure what you are after but if you want the panel to come up after you click the button and you want to the buttons to go way you can set them to not visible. `    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==login_bt) {
            loginPanel.setVisible(true);
            login_bt.setVisible(false);
            add_bt.setVisible(false);
            search_bt.setVisible(false);
            remove_bt.setVisible(false);
        }
    }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this worked just fine.. still i am looking for what's the reason that buttons are overlapping the panel because my previous codes never faced this issue but still Thanks to you that i can move on from this situation. Now I just want to know what's causing the overlap so i know the exact solution next time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a layout manager:

```
loginPanel.setLayout(null);
```

I highly recommend you learn about Java Swing Layout Managers:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Developing a fat client using Swing without a layout manager is like digging your own grave. I have never seen this before…

Comment: I have used layout on frame and panel both if you see the code.

Comment: No, in your code there is `jf.setLayout(null);` and `loginPanel.setLayout(null);`, so you don't use a layout manager.

Comment: Ohh i get it i'll go through docs.oracle Thanks for the answer if you can give me an example then i might understand it better.

Comment: I don't want to offend you, but: The use of layout managers is the absolute basics for creating a user interface with Swing. You should really consider going through a Swing tutorial, watching a course on YouTube or Udemy, or reading a book about UI development with Java Swing.